# exponential square root integral in denominator and numerator

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$ \int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{-1+ e^{2x}}}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Not sure where I messed up the formatting, but the denominator is suppose to be under a square root. Sorry for any confusion. I am trying to integrate this by $u$-sub and am getting lost. I under stand I should choose $u$ to be the whole denominator, but its not working out, I keep getting that the derivative of the denominator to be the whole equation itself and get stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = e^x$.  Then the integral becomes

\begin{align}
\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-1}} &= \int \frac{\sec t \tan t \,dt}{\tan t} \tag{$u = \sec t$} \\
&= \int \sec t \, dt \\
&= \ln|\sec t + \tan t| + C \\
&= \ln|u + \sqrt{u^2-1}| + C \\
&= \ln|e^x + \sqrt{e^{2x}-1}| + C
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint...alternatively you can substitute $e^x=\cosh u$